# Getting the current URL and title from WebView

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, xcode4, webkit

I am trying to get the current URL and title from the WebView. I've used this for the URL

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame
{
    // Only report feedback for the main frame.
    if (frame == [sender mainFrame]){
        NSString *url = [[[[frame provisionalDataSource] request] URL] absoluteString];
        [addressBar setStringValue:url];
    }
}
```

and this for the title:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didReceiveTitle:(NSString *)title forFrame:(WebFrame *)frame
{
    // Report feedback only for the main frame.
    if (frame == [sender mainFrame]){
        [[sender window] setTitle:title];
    }
}
```

This code comes straight from Apple's WebKit Objective-C Programming Guide. I only slightly modified the URL method to the addressBar instead of textField. But it doesn't work. The addressBar field is never populated with the URL of the page and the window title doesn't update ether. Everything is connected correctly in interface builder. Why won't it work?

Comment: Check whether the delegate functions get called. If not set the delegate for the Webview.

Answer (score 1):

If the page has already loaded then it is not a provisionaldatasource, replace this with

```
[[[[frame dataSource] request] URL] absoluteString];
```

Comment: I've tried that but it still doesn't work. I still haven't had any luck with this.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I myself don't know. But what I have found is a great website with tutorials one of which is to make an RSS feed and in that it takes the title from the RSS. You'll see it if your scroll down. Hope you can modify it to work!!

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2636/how-to-make-a-simple-rss-reader-iphone-app-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Here's you you get this working.

1. **Set up your `frameLoadDelegate` for the `WebView` object**. In your visual interface, control-drag from your `WebView` element to your `NSWindow` that is containing the `WebView`. When you release the mouse, a small black drop-down menu will appear. Select `frameLoadDelegate`. Once you've done this, messages such as `webView:DidReceiveTitle:forFrame` will be sent to the instance of your `NSWindow`.
2. **Create a Subclass out of `NSWindow` and assign your `NSWindow` object to this subclass**. Since this new child object will inherit everything from `NSWindow`, it will receive the `webView:DidReceiveTitle:forFrame` message.
3. **Paste in your code above into this new child class**. This effectively overrides the method definitions from the parent class, and gives you autonomous control over what happens.

Hope that helps.